# JQM submit form with AJAX cause errors with redirect

Tags: jquery-mobile, paypal

I'm using prestashop (1.4), I've installed mobile theme module for mobile client that uses jqm (1.3.2) on top of jquery (1.9.1)

Now, in the mobile version, The paypal module fails when clicking on a form that suppose to load the paypal page - it display 'error loading page' on the screen.

I tried to compare the HTTP request headers on the desktop and the mobile and found that there is an extra 'X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest' header in the mobile.

Therefore I figured that the jqm grabs all form submit and send them as ajax requests.

I think this cause a problem: the srv code redirect to paypal.com, but since it's an ajax request it cannot load the page...

or am I missing something???

The question is: how to prevent jqm from garbing the form and submitting it with ajax?

any idea, or solution to this issue is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

download the file http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js

set your code to use this file.

in line: 4863, after `$.mobile.document.delegate( "form", "submit", function( event ) {`

add the following lines:

```
        prventAjax = $(this).attr("prventAjax");
        if (prventAjax == 'true') return true;
```

now in the form orignal html form add attribute: `prventAjax='true'`

i.e.

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" prventAjax='true'>
```

this solves the problem for me.